# How to update rdd periodically in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

My code is something like:

```py
sc = SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)

initRDD = sc.parallelize('path_to_data')
lines = ssc.socketTextStream('localhost', 9999)
res = lines.transform(lambda x: x.join(initRDD))

res.pprint()
```

And my question is that `initRDD` need to **be updated every day in midnight**.

I try to this way:

```py
sc = SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)

lines = ssc.socketTextStream('localhost', 9999)


def func(rdd):
    initRDD = rdd.context.parallelize('path_to_data')
    return rdd.join(initRDD)


res = lines.transform(func)

res.pprint()
```

But it seems that `initRDD` will be updated per 30s which same to `batchDuration`

Is there any good ideal

Comment: Will an answer in Scala help you? This is possible in Scala, but I don't know the nuances of mutable references in pySpark.

Comment: @maasg Yes and thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to check for a deadline before the `transform`. The check is a simple comparison and hence cheap to do at each batch interval:

```scala
def nextDeadline() : Long = {
  // assumes midnight on UTC timezone.
  LocalDate.now.atStartOfDay().plusDays(1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()
}
// Note this is a mutable variable!
var initRDD = sparkSession.read.parquet("/tmp/learningsparkstreaming/sensor-records.parquet")
// Note this is a mutable variable!
var _nextDeadline = nextDeadline()

val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
// we use the foreachRDD as a scheduling trigger. 
// We don't use the data, only the execution hook
lines.foreachRDD{ _ => 
    if (System.currentTimeMillis > _nextDeadline) {
      initRDD = sparkSession.read.parquet("/tmp/learningsparkstreaming/sensor-records.parquet")
      _nextDeadline = nextDeadline()
    }
}
// if the rdd was updated, it will be picked up in this stage.
val res = lines.transform(rdd => rdd.join(initRDD))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Another question acrodding to your code: Do I need to call initRDD.persist() or initRDD .unpersist() manually in foreachRDD()?